# Like she's never danced before - did she or she didn't

Tags: meaning, past-tense, songs

I have a questions that bugs me for quite some time and no one could explain it to me properly.
In a song "Maniac" by Michael Sembello we have the line

> And she's dancing like she's never danced before

Does it mean that she has danced before but now she dances in a different manner or that she never danced and this is her first time? What is the correct meaning and how to say the other one?

Thanks

Comment: See [ell.se] This Q may be migrated.

Comment: When “no-one” could explain that to you properly, how exactly did they try? What did you really want to ask, please?

It’s none too easy to translate your Question and still, “she has danced before but now she dances in a different manner” might and “this is her first time” does not match your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first one.  It means she has danced before, but is now dancing in a way that she has not danced before.

Comment: In the context, it means she is dancing **as if** she has never danced before, not in a way different from before.